# Cloning by javascript an image base64 fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, base64, clone

I need to clone an html block which has some imgs inside, just like this:

```
<span class="slides_container" id="rotator1">
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="photoInfo">imagenes 1</div>
       <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j...FHFf/Z" width="600" height="400" alt="pic1">           
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slide">
      <div class="photoInfo">imagenes 1</div>
       <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j...FHFf/Z" width="600" height="400" alt="pic2">           
      </div>
   </div>
</span>
```

Then I use this jquery code to clone this block:

```
$('#mediaViewerSlides').append(content.clone());
```

As result, only the first image cloned on its src attr has at the end of the base64 string something like a GET parameter like this: src="...FHFf/Z?133487557212"
I can't get know how this value appears or why, obviously this extra data on the base64 string makes the image invalid, and it breaks everything else.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle example that demonstrates that

Comment: That appears to be a UNIX time-stamp in milliseconds. Probably added via jQuery to make sure the image doesn't load from cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong either with your code or the Base64 string.

Just found a random image on the web, [converted it to base64 here](http://base64img.com), and cloned it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/yzjmC/) with no such problems, so it's probably not jQuery adding the querystring.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help, debugging deeper into the code I found the problem inside other plugin I didn't thought could be the cause. It was the slides.jquery.js it adds a timestamp at the end of the string to avoid cache issues, asuming the src attr is a path, apparently it was not created thinking of base64 images. Thanks to all for your help, it makes me find the cause of the fail.

Comment: Always nice when people find the errors themselves, best way to learn. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the time-stamp is being added, but instead of cloning the whole object, maybe you can create a new one and set it's `src` attribute to the same value:

```
$('#mediaViewerSlides').append('<img src="' + content.attr('src') + '" width="600" height="400" />');
```

This assumes that `content` is a reference to one of the images with a base64 source.

If the time-stamp is being added to the pre-cloned element then you could strip it from the `src` when you create the new element:

```
var source = content.attr('src');

//if the source includes a question-mark, then get everything before the character
if (source.indexOf('?') > -1) {
    source = source.split('?')[0];
}
$('#mediaViewerSlides').append('<img src="' + source + '" width="600" height="400" />');
```

Comment: Thanks I already found the solution. I cannot use your idea 'cause the the mediaViewerSlides is a div that has to contain a set of divs containing images (it's a slideShow), and there are X number of these sets which are loades dynamically. Thanks after all.

Comment: You would just select the parent of the elements, then select all of them, loop through them, doing work on each...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you **HAVE** to clone this div. Why don't you just keep a reference to the source of the image and add that to a cloned version of the container.

Comment: Because it is not just one image, I am working with a set of images, a slideshow; and in the application there are a lot of these sets, the mediaViewer has to load dynamically one or another. As I saw it seems I didn't provide enough context in my question, as it's my first one, further I'll be more clear. Thanks after all.

Comment: No problem, glad that you found a solution.